# Server execution failed creating Outlook Application

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to send from a mail list using Outlook15.

I wrote the following, that loops through 16 cells with mail addresses, and attaches pdf files.

I get:

> "run time error '-2146959355(80080005)':
> server execution failed"

When I debug `Set outlookapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")` is highlited.

```vb
Sub SndEmail()
'define variables and their types'
Dim address As String
Dim subject As String
Dim message As String
Dim filename As String
Dim outlookapp As Object
Dim outlookmailitem As Object
Dim myAttachments As Object
Dim path As String
Dim lastrow As String
Dim attachment As String
'x will be row index we loop through'
Dim x As Integer

x = 61

Do While x < 77
        
    Set outlookapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set outlookmailitem = outlookapp.CreateItem(0)
    Set myAttachments = outlookmailitem.Attachments
    'taking the file path from cells in excel'
    path = sheet1.Cells(x, 4)
    address = sheet1.Cells(x, 3)
    subject = "hello world"
    attachment = path
        
    outlookmailitem.To = address
    outlookmailitem.CC = ""
    outlookmailitem.BCC = ""
    outlookmailitem.subject = subject
    'taking the body content from cell 56'
    outlookmailitem.Body = sheet1.Cells(56, 3)
                
    myAttachments.Add (attachment)
    outlookmailitem.Display
    outlookmailitem.Send
        
    address = ""
    x = x + 1
Loop
        
Set outlookapp = Nothing
Set outlookmailitem = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Try moving that line out of the loop

Comment: Multiple possibilities. Suggested search https://www.google.ca/search?biw=1556&bih=937&ei=wEP8X5icDYXz5gKDg46oBw&q=outlook+vba+run+time+error+%27-2146959355%2880080005%29+stackoverflow.com&oq=outlook+vba+run+time+error+%27-2146959355%2880080005%29+stackoverflow.com&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoECCEQClC2qgNYgbEDYP61A2gAcAB4AIABT4gB2AKSAQE1mAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesABAQ&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiY_K6G8JPuAhWFuVkKHYOBA3UQ4dUDCA0&uact=5 Pick out some that look promising. Edit the question with what you picked as most promising and the suggested solutions you tried.

Comment: i tried all of them unfortunatly.. is it possible that office 2013 cant automate mail sending through VBA?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new instances of these objects for each loop:

```
Set outlookapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set outlookmailitem = outlookapp.CreateItem(0)
Set myAttachments = outlookmailitem.Attachments
```

If you are familiar with C/C++, Java etc. the **Set** in VBA equals **new** in C/C++/Java

So put these lines outside (before) the loop

Comment: Hey, i tried to move it out of the loop and it did not change the error. it still highlighted " Set outlookapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")" . more so, i tried to send email without the loop (a single mail to  just one address) and the same error turns up. so i think it probably not loop related..

Comment: Please follow these guidelines if you want proper help:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Right about the loop, wrong about "set" - it is not the same as "new".  In this particular case, "CreateObject" is the equivalent of "new". "set"  is used with COM objects - it means increment the reference counter and store in a variable.

Comment: Only the CreateObject line needs to be outside the loop.